# Using createElement with a string gets an undefined error even though it exists in scope

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Pretty self-explanatory from the code below I think.  The example is obviously slightly contrived, but I want to use a string so that I can dynamically update the component.

```
import CardTypeSeed from 'card/card_type_seed';

_card() {
  console.log(CardTypeSeed);
  React.createElement(eval("CardTypeSeed"), null);
  // React.createElement(CardTypeSeed, null); this works
}
```

Console output:

[image]

Comment: Why are you `eval`ing it?

Comment: Just addressed this in the question, I want to dynamically update the component and don't want to have a huge switch statement.

Comment: Just store all the different components in an object, and do `React.createElement(allComponents[someString], null)`. That is, if I understand you correctly, and "CardTypeSeed" represents a dynamic string in your real code.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically update? Seems like you'd be better off asking a new question asking how to do what you want without `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel does not support `eval` and makes no guarantees that `eval` blocks will work as expected. `CardTypeSeed` in this case is being renamed to something else but isn't being renamed inside the `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that explains why this worked before I was using Babel.